# Connect to SVN from Active Choices Parameters plug-in using groovy

Tags: jenkins, svn, groovy

In Active Choices Parameters I use a groovy script for reading the jar file from a specific path,and populate the drop-down menu with those jar files:

```
Jar=[]
path = "/home/users/jars/"
new File(path).eachFileMatch(~/.*.jar/) {
      Jar.add(it.getName())
}  
return Jar.sort()
```

I don't know if is possible, using groovy, to connect to SVN with user and password to "read" and display in drop-down all the jar's from SVN specific directory?!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some google search I found this method adapted a little bit.This show the dirs from specific SVN location.

```
def user = hudson.model.User.current();
def a = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getAuthentication()
def userId = user.getId() 
def pass =a.getCredentials()
def svnurl = 'yourSvnUrl'
def dirs = [] 
def command = ['svn', 'list', svnurl , '--username' , 'yourSvnUser' , '--password' , 'YourSvnPassword' ]
def proc = command.execute()
print command
proc.in.eachLine {dirs.add(it) }
return dirs
```